# Load PDF into external viewer from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have disabled the internal PDF viewer plugin in Chrome. However PDFs now simply fail to do anything, instead of loading externally.

[image]

Is there a setting I need to modify?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the link to chrome://plugins/

Find Chrome PDF Viewer in the list, and click Enable:

[image]

You may also wish to click Always Allowed.

Comment: I went through this sequence a number of times but did not resolve it.